# Function to convert URL hash parameters into object (key value pairs)

Tags: javascript, hash

Consider this string: `#page?param1=a&param2=b&param3=c`

A hybrid application I have been working on uses `window.location.hash` to route the application to the right page. Often, these URLs contain parameters after the hash. Sure, this isn't standard, but it's a good solution that works nicely for our application.

I need to create a function that will take all of the parameters in the hash and return them in a object, for example:  `{param: value}`.

I have tried other questions solution's that involve `window.location.search` but sadly that just returns an empty string when the parameters are after a hash.

My attempt looks like this:

`return JSON.parse('{"' + decodeURI(window.location.hash).replace(/"/g, '\\"').replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g,'":"') + '"}');`

The solution is taken from another question that uses `window.location.search` but using `window.location.hash` doesn't quite work properly, the first parameter (after the question mark) shows as undefined.

How can I create a function that would return hash parameters in an object?

The desired result for the string above would be this:

```
{ param1: 'a', param2: 'b', param3: 'c' }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
function parseParms(str) {
    var pieces = str.split("&"), data = {}, i, parts;
    // process each query pair
    for (i = 0; i < pieces.length; i++) {
        parts = pieces[i].split("=");
        if (parts.length < 2) {
            parts.push("");
        }
        data[decodeURIComponent(parts[0])] = decodeURIComponent(parts[1]);
    }
    return data;
}
```

This is taken from the `.parseParms()` method of a [larger set of functionality on github](https://github.com/jfriend00/parseurl) I wrote for parsing a URL into all its pieces.

Input is a string in the form of:

```
"aaa=1&bbb=99&name=Bob"
```

and it will return an object like this:

```
{aaa: 1, bbb: 99, name: "Bob"}
```

So, if you have other things in the string besides just the parameters above, then you would need to remove those first before calling this function.

Working demo:

```js
function parseParms(str) {
    var pieces = str.split("&"), data = {}, i, parts;
    // process each query pair
    for (i = 0; i < pieces.length; i++) {
        parts = pieces[i].split("=");
        if (parts.length < 2) {
            parts.push("");
        }
        data[decodeURIComponent(parts[0])] = decodeURIComponent(parts[1]);
    }
    return data;
}

console.log(parseParms("aaa=1&bbb=99&name=Bob"));
```

Comment: That's great thanks! Yes, I think the best way to do it would just be to split and remove everything before the '?'

Comment: This solution can't work with arrays in urls. Please see my example below.

Comment: @t1gor - So you downvoted the accepted answer that did exactly what the OP asked for, but doesn't meet some other requirement that was not in the question?  Really?  You're welcome to promote your own answer and try to convince the world it's a better answer, but you don't generally downvote good answers that meet the requirements stated in the question.  Downvotes are generally reserved for wrong answers or answers that show bad practices.

Comment: @jfriend00 didn't really mean to offend you, sorry. Will restore the vote when I'll be allowed to.

Comment: @t1gor - I added a working demo so you should be able to restore it now.

Comment: If using the string provided in the question (and returned by `location.hash`), you might want to add this as the first line to the function to strip the leading hash:
`if (str.startsWith('#')) { str = str.substr(1); }`

Answer (score 2):

the `foreEach` method on arrays makes it even shorter:

```
const result = {};
hash.split('&').forEach(item => {
    result[item.split('=')[0]] = decodeURIComponent(item.split('=')[1]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function parseParms(str) 
{
  var pieces = str.split( "&" ), 
      data = {}, 
      i, parts, key;

  // Process each query pair
  for ( i = 0; i < pieces.length; i++ ) {
    parts = pieces[i].split( "=" );

    // No value, only key
    if ( parts.length < 2 ) {
      parts.push( "" );
    }

    key = decodeURIComponent( parts[ 0 ] );
    value = decodeURIComponent( parts[ 1 ] );

    // Key is an array
    if ( key.indexOf( "[]" ) !== -1 ) {
      key = key.substring( 0, key.indexOf( "[]" ) );

      // Check already there
      if ( "undefined" === typeof data[ key ] ) {
        data[ key ] = [];
      }

      data[ key ].push( value );
    } else {
      data[ key ] = value;
    }
  }
  return data;
}
```

Working example can be found here: https://jsbin.com/xitemecuvi/edit?js,console

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function queryStringToObject (url){
const urlObj = new URL(url);
const queryString = urlObj.search.substring(1);
const queryStringArray = queryString.split('&')
let obj={};
queryStringArray.forEach(item=>{
  let itemArr = item.split('=')
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty(itemArr[0])){
    if(typeof obj[`${itemArr[0]}`] == 'string'){
      obj[`${itemArr[0]}`]=[obj[`${itemArr[0]}`]]
    }
    obj[`${itemArr[0]}`].push(itemArr[1])
  }
  else{
    obj[`${itemArr[0]}`]=itemArr[1]
  }

})

return obj;

}

console.log('--OUTPUT--',queryStringToObject('http://localhost:3000/api?brand=samsung&brand=apple&brand=lg&category=mobile'))
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.